# Why does this function only log to console after two clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function doesn't log any values after the first click of a checkbox, only from the second click onwards. Can anyone see why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateDays() {
    $('#my_div').find('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
        var pass = parseInt($('input[name="other_1"]:checked').val(), 10) // 1, 2, 3
        var days = $('#my_div').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
        console.log(days, pass);
        if (days == pass) {
            $('#my_div').find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            $('#my_div').find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
    $('input[name="other_1"]').change(function () {
        $('#my_div').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
            'checked': false,
            'disabled': false
        });
        if (parseInt($(this).val(), 10) == 3) {
            $('#my_div').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
                'checked': true,
                'disabled': false
            });
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

The console isn's showing any errors or warnings.

If you wish to try out the code, please visit this link:

https://secure.ukipme.com/forms_conf/mmx14c/conf_form_new.php

(It's the Conference Pass / Day Select section you need... selecting the correct number of days for the pass type you have chosen automatically disables any other days. i.e. Select a 2-day pass, and once you have selected two days, the third checkbox disables. However, it doesn't work for the Session (1-day) pass until you have clicked twice.

The validation function is called `onclick`, on all/any of the checkboxes: `<input name="other_2" type="checkbox" id="other_2" value="YES" onClick="validateDays();">`

Comment: When is the `validateDays` function called?

Comment: onclick, on all/any of the checkboxes: `<input name="other_2" type="checkbox" id="other_2" value="YES" onClick="validateDays();">`

Comment: You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot get the javascript working outside of the page, (i.e. in a fiddle), as the page/javascript throughout is so complex. I did spend a good time trying, this is as far as I got: http://jsfiddle.net/6fRPr/3/

Comment: The problem is because you are assigning the click handler to the checkboxes after they have been clicked for the first time, and the validateDays function is called.

Comment: on clicking checkbox, firstly validateDays() is called and then inside its click event is called. makes me little confused. @_@

don't you think you should only using one either validateDays() or click event handler ??

Comment: So I need to remove the click event from within the function, somehow?

Comment: I can confirm that removing the click event from the function gets this working, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code

```
<input name="other_2" type="checkbox" id="other_2" value="YES" onClick="validateDays();">
```

The click handler doesn't get registered until you actually click it. If you bind this on ready instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my_div').find('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
        var pass = parseInt($('input[name="other_1"]:checked').val(), 10) // 1, 2, 3
        var days = $('#my_div').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
        console.log(days, pass);
        if (days == pass) {
            $('#my_div').find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            $('#my_div').find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
    $('input[name="other_1"]').change(function () {
        $('#my_div').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
            'checked': false,
            'disabled': false
        });
        if (parseInt($(this).val(), 10) == 3) {
            $('#my_div').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
                'checked': true,
                'disabled': false
            });
        }
    });
});
```

then remove the onclick:

```
<input name="other_2" type="checkbox" id="other_2" value="YES">
```

as the `$(..).click();` does this.